# Grunt Warning: Task "compass:server"

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, bower, compass

I know there are any other post about this problem,but right now no one have solved my problem.
I'm trying tu use Grunt on a project with node,compass,git.
After I've installed node i use the following statement:
npm install
npm install bower
gem install compass
npm install git
npm grunt-cli
npm install -g grunt grunt-cli

then when I use
grunt serve
I get the following message:

> Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

> > 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning:
jit-grunt: Plugin for the "compass" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "compass:server" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2015-11-20 15:54:16 UTC)
loading tasks  59ms  █████████████████████████████████████████████ 95%
Total 62ms Use --force to continue.

```
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Execution Time (2015-11-20 15:54:12 UTC)
wiredep:app        981ms  ████████████ 28%
wiredep:test        75ms  █ 2%
wiredep:sass       107ms  ██ 3%
concurrent:server   2.2s  ████████████████████████████ 63%

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's too late, now is Now 20'16.

When I delete `"grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.3",` in `package.json` and delete the `node_modules` dictionary. And then typed `npm install` and `grunt serve`, same output show up.

So, just check is there something like `"grunt-contrib-compass": "^***"` in your `package.json`, if there are not(hopefully), just type:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev
npm install
grunt serve
```